# Adding razor variable in view controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was wondering if it were possible to call a razor variable in a view controller?

Basically I'm trying to replicate the process from this video with a couple of differences: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7i1G6CeOiI

For example, I'm building a website that takes text input from a form and emails it  to a central email address. After building the form on an html page, I then use razor to create a variable equal to each input box

ex:

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="inputOne" />

@{
 var input1 = Request["inputOne"];
}
```

From there, I created a string that will put all of the variables together to create the message body of the email.

ex:

```
string messageBody = "input one: " + input1 + "input two: " + input2 + ect.ect.ect.;
```

Now here's where I'm a bit lost. The way it's done in the video above, the instructor hard codes the message sent in the email. Obviously that wouldn't work in my situation as the message body relies on user input. I thought it would be easy enough to call the "messageBody" string and that would be that - apparently not. "The name 'messageBody' doesn't exist in the current context". I'm wondering exactly how or if I could call the "messageBody" string in the controller? Or perhaps an entirely different method would suit my needs better?

Comment: Submit your form and read it in the action method which handles the form submit. Did you try that approach ?

Comment: You should never get data from `Request` in MVC code.  Instead, use model binding and view models.

Comment: You should move that logic to the controller and pass it to the view in a model.

Answer (score 0):

Create two action, what returns Views inside your Controller. One for the GET and one for the POST.

Plus create your model you will use, your model should have the InputOne property, so looks like this:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public string InputOne { get; set; }
}
```

The actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Example()
    {
        var model = new ExampleViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Example(ExampleViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // Process the model as you wish...

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(AnotherAction));
    }
```

Create the corresponding View (Views folder/YourControllerName/Example.cshtml)
In the view include your viewmodel, and implement the form:

```
@model YourProjectName.Project.Models.ExampleViewModel

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Example", "YourController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InputOne)

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    }
</div>
```

Hope this helps!